# How to Extract Desired Key-Value pairs from Multiple Objects in Array in JS File on Client-Side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, blob, filereader

I am required to extract desired key-values from a large `.js` file essentially containing an array of objects with fixed defined keys in `json` format by uploading it on the client-side.

I want to extract desired keys and values from each object. But the problem is that the file is `2+ GB` in size and can't be uploaded all at once. So I need to at best split the file into small chunks and extract the required keys' values.

The `.js` file looks like the following, and let say I want to extract only `b` and `d` keys' values from each object.

```
var data = [{
  "a": "...",
  "b": [{
    "b-1": "...",
    "b-2": 3,
    "b-3": {"b-3-1": "..."}
  }, {...}, {...}],
  "c": false,
  "d": 25,
  ...
}, ..., {...}]
```

I've read about `FileReader` and `Blob` Web APIs but don't know which one to use and how so in such a way that when splitting it into small chunks each chunk carries an entire object.

Please kindly help me on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a streaming JSON parser for Node, e.g.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stream

If this is a one-of-job you may want to look into [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), (it's like sed for JSON data - you can use it to slice and filter data) e.g. piping data in and out of it (or you could automate it as well)

```
cat file.json | jq '.a' | less
```

See: https://shapeshed.com/jq-json/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I've checked them and seems pretty convinced using JSONStream. I may look stupid here but am confused as to how to parse my file so to get desired values from stream. Can you [;ease provide any working example that relates to my case?